# why is anonymous class able to access the local variable

Tags: java

```
public String doSomething(){
    int i=5;

    return TestEmploye.doStringstuff(new UpperConcat() { //no name of this class
        @Override
        public String upperAndConcat(String s1, String s2) {
            System.out.println(i);
            return s1.toUpperCase()+s2.toUpperCase();
        }
    },"hello ","vishnu");
}
```

I have read some documentation and stackiverflow article and as per them a local inner class(class within method) or anonymous class cannot access local variable but in the above code

i have created an interface upperAndConcat with a single Method with two string arguements [public String upperAndConcat(String s1, String s2);]
TestEmployee has static method doStringstudd which i called directly

Now the question is i have decalred int i=5 as local variable inside dosomething method how is the anonymous class able to access it?

Comment: Can you show the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

BytheWay i got my ans...actually the anonymous class was able to access i because it was effectively final...

Comment: Check the section with heading
Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope, and Declaring and Accessing Members of the Anonymous Class

Comment: You probably read it can't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anonymous Classes, The Java<sup>TM</sup> Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing):

> - An anonymous class cannot access local variables ... that are not declared as `final` or effectively final.

The variable `i` is not changed, so it is effectively final. For this reason, its value can be used by the anonymous class.